# Installing electron on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7, electron

I tried to install electron js in windows 7 32 bits with node.js v=12.13.10
and npm v=6.11.2

I tried to install normal but when it start it gives me:

```
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
```

I tried like in electron documentation 
(just copie past) .When I run

```
npm start
```

It give me te following error

```
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process

 > first-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\app
 > electron

 C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\app\node_modules\electron\index.js:14
 throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete 
 node_modules/electron and try installing again')
   ^

 Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete 
 node_modules/electron and try installing again
 at getElectronPath 
 (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\app\node_modules\←[4melectron←[24m\index.js:14:11)
 at Object.<anonymous> 
 (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\app\node_modules\←[4melectron←[24m\index.js:18:18)
  ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)←[39m
  ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)←[39m
  ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)←[39m
  ←[90m    at Function.Module._load 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)←[39m
 ←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)←[39m
 ←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
  at Object.<anonymous> 
  (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\app\node_modules\←[4melectron←[24m\cli.js:3:16)
 ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)←[39m
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! first-app@0.1.0 start: `electron`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the first-app@0.1.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely                   
  additional logging output above.
```

---

this is my package.json file

```
 {
 "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "main.js",
  "description": "my first app",
 "scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"electron": "^7.0.1"
 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? When you ran npm install --save electron did you notice any errors similar to what is below the end of this comment? (note unique named folder, yours may vary - electron-download-qmOLFP)

It may also be a permission issue in which you will need to run your cmd prompt as an administrator.

(node:21604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\newuser\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-download-qmOLFP\electron-v7.1.1-win32-x64.zip'

Comment: I run it in administrator and still don't work,It worked when I reinstalled node js and npm